# Derivation of basis and dimension of a multilinear map $\Psi:V^s\to V$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, multilinear-algebra

I'm reading linear algebra and came up to the topic of linear map representations as matrices. More specifically for a dim $n$ vector space $V$, the space $Lin(V,V)$ of maps $T:V\to V$ is isomorphic to the space of $n\times n$ matrices. This leads to dimension $n^2$.

Let $Mult(V^s,V)$ be the space of all $s$-multilinear maps that send $s$ vectors in $V$ to some vector in $V$. e.g. if $A\in Mult(V_s,V)$, then $A:V^s\to V$ so that $A(v_1,\ldots,v_s)\in V$, where $v_i\in V$.

For $Mult(V^s,V)$, intuitively I can extend the simpler $Lin(V,V)$ case to say that its dimension could be $n^{s+1}$. But I'm not really satisfied.

To explicitly derive the dimension, one needs to come up with a linearly independent that spans the vector space. But I'm struggling to come up with such a set for $Lin(V,V)$ or $Mult(V^s,V)$. Sure I can prove that the former is isomorphic to the space of $n\times n$ matrices, and then go on to say that their dimensions are thus equal. But just out of curiosity, how do I even come up with a basis of linear (for $Lin(V,V)$) or multilinear (for $Mult(V^s,V)$) maps?

Is this even feasible?

Comment: Your notation for $Mult(V^s,V)$ is a little unclear to me. Can you write what this means precisely?

Comment: Sure, I'll edit the question and also clarify in this comment. $Mult(V^s,V)$ is the space of all $s$-multilinear maps that send $s$ vectors in $V$ to some vector in $V$. e.g. if $A\in Mult(V_s,V)$, then $A:V^s\to V$ so that $A(v_1,\ldots,v_s)\in V$, where $v_i\in V$. Hope that clarifies!

Comment: If $e_1,\cdots,e_n$ is a basis then for every sequence $(i_1,\cdots,i_{s+1})$ of indices there is a multilinear map sending $(e_{i_1},\cdots,e_{i_s})$ to $e_{i_{s+1}}$ and other tuples of basis vectors to $0$. These multilinear maps form a basis for all of the multilinear maps, and there are $n^{s+1}$ of them.

Comment: @runway44: Hmm so a matrix with just a $1$ in $i,j$-th place, and zeros everywhere else, basically represents an automorphism that sends $e_j$ to $e_i$. What you say is a generalization of that - a basis map is a map that sends some combo of $s$ basis vectors to some basis vector. Thanks for pointing this out! I'll try to prove span and independence with this info..